# Desktop Background changing issues

Tags: windows-7, desktop, desktop-customization

My desktop background doesn't change, it seems that the ease of access option "remove background image (if possible)" is always checked, even after I uncheck it, it resets to checked, I managed to change the background from black to white but nothing more.
I have tried regedit.exe fixes, I have tried reeboting, creating new accounts, nothing works, can someone please help? 
I'm running windows 7 home basic.

Answer (score 0):

On the left side of the "ease of access center" go to the "change administrative settings" and uncheck the box "Apply all settings to the logon desktop".  Change your theme to anything except the "High Contrast" themes.
Lastly choose a different background.